# Modern C++ Policy Based Design vs Old style #ifdef

Tags: c++

I am developing an application which, when compiled for some specific target, will or will not do some specific actions.
Traditional approach to this kind of problem, taken from C, is adding a lot of #ifdef instructions everywhere. But this leads to very bad code, unreadable and almost unmaintainable.
There is, however, a better, modern C++ approach, which is Policy Based Design, by Alexandrescu. But it requires totally different thinking, preparing the appplication to be aware of the policies from scratch. With the #ifdefs approach, if you have already a huge code base, you implement a new feature and you suddenly recognize a need to differentiate something based on some target, i.e. to do something or not to do, for example, you can just drop an #ifdef instruction wherever you want, it won't break your existing code, it'll do what you expect it to do. This is not the case with Policy Based Design (PBD). You have to desing the application from scratch to be aware of the policies, and only then you can use them.

There is, however, another problem. Let's say I have already designed the application to be PBD aware. Now I would like to have a compile switch, I mean cmake switch, to choose this or that policy. I don't want to have to modify my e.g. main function, to construct the rest of the program with Policy B, instead of Policy A. Is there a clean way to achieve this goal? Some kind of dependency injection for C++? I think a solution would be to have e.g. two files "main.cpp" with the main function, and use for compilation one or another, based on some environment variable. But maybe there's a better way?

Also, I would like to ask about your experiences with such problems, with #ifdefs and PBD.

Comment: If you use cmake then you can generate a config.h containing the necessary type definitions based on input switches.

Comment: Oh, right, that's a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: Any other useful hint? How do you do such things?